Webots2023b renderer has black border
During one of my experiments, I noticed that the renderer's perspective seemed to have shifted. A black area appeared, which I circled in red in the image below. What is this? How can I restore it?

In fact, this is VERY HARMFUL to me. Because the renderer is offset,  I can't use the mouse to click on the link in the scene. Instead, I have to click on the position before it is offset. However, I can only guess at this position.

Can you create an issue on the Webots repo? Please put details about your OS. We need a way to reproduce the issue to fix it
